# Agda - Why is this case required to type check? In a simple proof that $forall m, 1 * m \equiv m$

Tags: agda

After defining the naturals, addition and multiplication as usual, I set to write a proof that 1 is a neutral element.

```
p : (n : ℕ) -> (1 * n) ≡ n
p zero = refl
p (suc m) = refl
```

Which is fine!

Since `refl` appears in both alternatives, I thought this should type-check:

```
p : (n : ℕ) -> (1 * n) ≡ n
p _ = refl
```

But this fails with:

```
1 * n != n of type ℕ
when checking that the expression refl has type (1 * n) ≡ n
```

What causes type to not check here?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to diagnose an error without a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), no matter how standard you think your definitions are.

Your error presumably comes from the fact `_+_` and `_*_` are defined like so:

```
0     + n = n
m     + 0 = m
suc m + n = suc (m + n)

0     * n = n
suc m * n = n + m * n
```

and so `1 * n = (suc 0) * n = n + 0 * n = n + 0` which is not judgmentally
equal to `n` because `_+_` is strict in its first argument and so won't
evaluate until that first argument is constructor-headed.

Matching on `n` to expose a constructor is enough for `_+_` to reduce:
`0 + 0` is `0` by the first equation and `suc m + 0` is `suc m` by the second.